# Scaling Bokeh according to screen

Tags: python, plot, scale, bokeh, figure

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNnGf.png), I have two plots in same row. I need to scale whole row according to screen size but maintain plot length ratio.

I tried with argument: `sizing_mode = 'scale width'`, but it doesn't work because it changes heights of plots.

```
p1 = figure(plot_width=NewRanges_Row1[0], plot_height=height, tools=[hover1, TOOLS], title="CHROMOSOME_1",
            toolbar_location="above", responsive = True)
p1.circle('x1', 'y1', fill_color=chromosome1_colors, line_color=chromosome1_colors,
          fill_alpha=chromosome1_transparency, size=7, source=source1)
p2 = figure(plot_width=NewRanges_Row1[1], plot_height=height, tools=[hover22, TOOLS], title="CHROMOSOME_22")
p2.circle('x22', 'y22', fill_color=chromosome22_colors, line_color=chromosome22_colors,
          fill_alpha=chromosome22_transparency, size=7, source=source22)
```

Where *p1* is first plot in row, and *p2* is second plot in row.

Is there a way to scale Bokeh figures automatically according to size of screen, while maintaining the ratio of widths in same row?

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh's responsive plotting functionality is still quite poor when it comes to complex layouts. The solution that I've found is to use Python's built in library to determine the screen resolution and then set the height and width values for each object.

```
import ctypes
screen_width = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
max_width = floor(96 * screen_width / 100)  # buffer to adjust
p1_width = 0.8*max_width 
p2_width = 0.2*max_width
```

However, this means that the web application is not truly responsive since it will not resize with the user's browser page as the screen resolution is determined only once when the application starts. If you need a more responsive app, you will need to look into doing that by tweaking the app's css and js.